# .htaccess website redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I need to make changes to my website but I do not want to make them to my live account until I am sure they are right. My account is with GoDaddy and the only way I can do that, according to them, is to move all my files to another folder and test my changes by going to that folder. Instead of calling Duphil.com from a web browser I use Duphil.com/DuphilWork. The coding in the .htaccess file will not let me stay in this folder.

Here is the coding:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?page=403

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^about/$ /index.php?page=about
RewriteRule ^oilfield/$ /index.php?page=oilfield
RewriteRule ^pipeline/$ /index.php?page=pipeline
RewriteRule ^safety/$ /index.php?page=safety
RewriteRule ^sales/$ /index.php?page=sales
RewriteRule ^contact/$ /index.php?page=contact
RewriteRule ^stateLicensures/$ /index.php?page=stateLicensures
RewriteRule ^keyPersonnel/$ /index.php?page=keyPersonnel
RewriteRule ^projectListings/$ /index.php?page=projectListings
RewriteRule ^legal/$ /index.php?page=legal
RewriteRule ^techDivision/$ /index.php?page=techDivision

RewriteRule ^equipment/$ /index.php?page=equipment
RewriteRule ^projectImages/$ /index.php?page=projectImages
RewriteRule ^contact/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=contact&contactName=$1
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The way you did your `.htaccess` is quite messy. A rule for every page has a number of disadvantages, not the least of which is that if you add a page, you'll have to update your `.htaccess`. Another disadvantage is that you can't simply add an exception, as you would have to add for each rule. However, one thing we can do is rewrite the page to itself and tell it isn't supposed to continue rewriting once it has done so:

```
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/(.*)$ DuphilWork/$1

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php
[..]
```

Now, this means you do still have to write your urls on the test site without rewriting. In other words, they'd have to be something like this: `Duphil.com/DuphilWork/index.php?page=oilfield`.

If you want to write the fancier urls in your test site as well, the only way with your current setup is to copy just about all the rules in your `.htaccess` and add `DuphilWork` to the match pattern and redirect path in one of the copies.

The real solution would of course to have a single rule like this:

```
RewriteCondition !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

And then make sure that index.php parses that page string correctly (which now includes making sure that the page exists. In that case it becomes trivial to solve your current problem. However, I do believe you should be able to make this work with the solutions I gave above.

---

Using the strategy I described above which involves copying everything, you would end up with something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?page=403

RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/$ /DuphilWork/index.php
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/about/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=about
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/oilfield/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=oilfield
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/pipeline/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=pipeline
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/safety/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=safety
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/sales/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=sales
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/contact/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=contact
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/stateLicensures/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=stateLicensures
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/keyPersonnel/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=keyPersonnel
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/projectListings/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=projectListings
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/legal/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=legal
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/techDivision/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=techDivision

RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/equipment/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=equipment
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/projectImages/$ /DuphilWork/index.php?page=projectImages
RewriteRule ^DuphilWork/contact/(.*)/$ /DuphilWork/ index.php?page=contact&contactName=$1

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^about/$ /index.php?page=about
RewriteRule ^oilfield/$ /index.php?page=oilfield
RewriteRule ^pipeline/$ /index.php?page=pipeline
RewriteRule ^safety/$ /index.php?page=safety
RewriteRule ^sales/$ /index.php?page=sales
RewriteRule ^contact/$ /index.php?page=contact
RewriteRule ^stateLicensures/$ /index.php?page=stateLicensures
RewriteRule ^keyPersonnel/$ /index.php?page=keyPersonnel
RewriteRule ^projectListings/$ /index.php?page=projectListings
RewriteRule ^legal/$ /index.php?page=legal
RewriteRule ^techDivision/$ /index.php?page=techDivision

RewriteRule ^equipment/$ /index.php?page=equipment
RewriteRule ^projectImages/$ /index.php?page=projectImages
RewriteRule ^contact/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=contact&contactName=$1
```

Comment: The .htaccess coding was done my someone else so that is why I did not know what it was trying to do. Do I need to change the coding you mentioned in the live version .htaccess or the one in the work folder or do I even need one in the work folder? Thanks.

Comment: Your .htaccess should be in the directory your script wants to redirect *from*, so that would be the one in the live version.

Comment: I have tried the changes and nothing is working, I think mainly because I am not sure what I am doing. I may have to try some changes in my PHP files instead of using .htaccess.

Comment: @user1810533: Do you want to be able to use the rewritten urls for the testing copy as well?

Comment: Yes I would like to use them for the testing copy also.

Comment: @user1810533: In that case, see the solution I added to my answer

Comment: I added the coding and now I get a 500 Internal Server Error.